# Through wood and break and many a fertile field: what is "break"?

Tags: meaning, poetry

A poem from *[A Canterbury Tale (1944)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Canterbury_Tale):*

> Six hundred years have passed. What would they see,
>   Dan Chaucer and his goodly company?
>   Today the hills and valleys are the same.
>   Gone are the forests since the enclosures came.
>   Hedgerows have sprung. The land is under plow,
>   And orchards bloom with blossom on the bough.
>   Sussex and Kent are like a garden fair,
>   But sheep still graze upon the ridges there.
>   The Pilgrims’ Way still winds above the weald,
>   Through wood and **break** and many a fertile field.

What could be the meaning of **break** here?
Could it be **[windbreak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windbreak)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the word is misspelled here. (Was this text taken from the original script or transcribed from the dialog?) It should be *brake*.

> **Brake** - a clump of brushes, brushwood, or briars. See also thicket. ([link](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brake))

Comment: Definitely - here's [a **valid** transcript](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JbnHvxuby54C&pg=PA51&dq=%22still+winds+above+the+weald%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GDNmVLe4JoKwaZOtgegF&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22still%20winds%20above%20the%20weald%22&f=false)

Comment: I first saw the word in subtitles when watching the movie, then googled and copied the text from [here](https://www.kcl.ac.uk/artshums/ahri/centres/clams/ACanterburyTale.pdf). Oh, so it's brake after all (thanks, @FumbleFingers). That explains it.

Comment: @CopperKettle: This one is right at the margins of my vocabulary. It didn't occur to me when I was looking at the question text - but it rang a bell when I saw this answer, so I was pretty optimistic I'd find the "correct" spelling in Google Books. It's not the same as [*The Missouri Breaks*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missouri_Breaks) (*great* movie! :) which are *"deep cuts or 'breaks' in the land [made by the river]"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Strangely, I knew the word, [it is used in a beautiful poem by Longfellow](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Slave_in_the_Dismal_Swamp), but it did not occur to me too. Thanks for the movie tip! (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle: If you ever get around to watching the movie, it's interesting to see how the two "mega-stars" (Brando & Nicholson) come across. Usually it's Nicholson who risks "hamming it up" (though he invariably *just* carries things off), but in this one he plays things pretty straight while Brando (successfully, imho) treads that fine line between the sublime and the ridiculous. I urge you to track it down and prepare to be spellbound!

Comment: I have heard of 'cane brakes' which is a thick clump of sugar cane.